# Passing jQuery.show() & jQuery.hide() as parameter to be applied on an element

Tags: jquery, show-hide, function-parameter

As the title reads, I'd like to pass show() & hide() jQuery functions as parameters in another function.

```
function applyActionOnClass(attr, action) {
    $('#salesonhold_table tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('status') == attr)
        $(this).action;
    });
}
```

Here is when I call my `applyActionOnClass` function:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkboxes', function () {
    var attr = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        applyActionOnClass(attr, show());
    else
        applyActionOnClass(attr, hide());
});
```

To explain a bit the purpose of this, I have a table and each of its `<tr>` has a `status` attribute which differs them from each other. I have two checkboxes on top of the table, one for each possible `status` value and I'd like to hide/show corresponding `<tr>` when checkboxes are triggered.

The trigger and stuff work fine but when it comes to `$(this).action;` it says `hide is not defined`. Any idea what I did wrong there?

Thank you so much !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass an anonymous function (or delegate) instead. This code handles that:

```
function applyActionOnClass(attr, func) {
    $('#salesonhold_table tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('status') == attr)
        func($(this));
    });
}
```

This code passes the delegate in:

```
$(document).on('change', '.checkboxes', function () {
    var attr = $(this).val();
    if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        applyActionOnClass(attr, function(e) { e.show(); });
    else
        applyActionOnClass(attr, function(e) { e.hide(); });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to change your function like so

```
function applyActionOnClass(attr, action) {
    $('#salesonhold_table tr').each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('status') == attr)
        $(this)[action]();
    });
}
```

Note `$(this)[action]();` You can see it at work here http://jsfiddle.net/t6rEE/ as a proof of concept (and I tried both with `hide` and `show`)

Comment: I upvoted anyway other solution. this was just a way to show a different approach and make my brain work further :)

Comment: Little jQuery mutual appreciation society going on here. ;)